# Setting gas for truffle

Tags: ethereum, truffle, go-ethereum, cryptocurrency, consensys-truffle

I'm running `truffle migrate` on main.  Also using geth. 
I originally left gas price and gas empty in truffle.js, but now it looks like this:

```
live: {
  network_id: 1,
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 8545,
  from: "3984bc76cb775d7866d1cd55c4f49e3d13d411d4",
  gas: 40000,
  gasPrice: 22000000000 // Specified in Wei
}
```

I seem to have a situation where I either have too much gas or not enough, with no possibility for the right amount.

```
 <   {
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "id": 2,
 <     "error": {
 <       "code": -32000,
 <       "message": "insufficient funds for gas * price + value"
 <     }
 <   }
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

...or...

```
 <   {
 <     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <     "id": 2,
 <     "error": {
 <       "code": -32000,
 <       "message": "exceeds block gas limit"
 <     }
 <   }
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: exceeds block gas limit
```

When I run `web3.eth.getBlock("latest")` in console, I get `gasLimit: 5000`.  When I set my gas at 5000 I get the insufficient funds message.  When I set it to 5001, I get "exceeds block gas limit".

So, all this seems to be telling me that the gasLimit should be set to 5000 or under 5000, but in that case I don't have sufficient funds to run the transaction.  Let's see...

I have:

gas: 5000,
  gasPrice: 22000000000 // Specified in Wei

5000 * 22000000000 = 1.1 * 10^14 = 110,000,000,000,000 Wei
1.1 * 10^14 / 10 ^ 18 (number of Wei in 1 Ether) = 1.1*10^-4 ETH

Here's the account I'm using: https://etherscan.io/address/0x3984bc76cb775d7866d1cd55c4f49e3d13d411d4.  As you can see, it has funds.  0.01738465 Ether at time of writing, to be precise.

Comment: Should be moved to ethereum.stackexchange.com. Gas limit 5000 seems way too low, have you tried much higher value like 100k? And have you succeeded on other networks than main?

Answer (score 2):

if you are on a test network, on [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc), the option -l or --gasLimit lets you set the gas available.

On geth, this post should help : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13730/how-to-increase-gas-limit-in-block-using-geth

Answer (score 1):

This randomly started working the following day.  One thing I noticed was that when I ran `web3.eth.getBlock("latest")` in truffle console yesterday, I was getting `gasLimit: 5000`, which was a way lower number than the network was reporting elsewhere.  Today I was getting `gasLimit: 6706583`.  I'm really not sure what caused the gas limit to increase locally, but whatever it was seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: when your ethereum node (Im using Geth) has not synced with the blockchain, it gives the gasLimit of the genesis block (block 0). This has a 5000 gaslimit which, of course, is too low to do anything. Possibly this is a failsafe to prevent you from sending tx's when not in sync..

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar issue. The version of truffle I was using was Truffle v4.0.1 (core: 4.0.1). If you downgrade to beta version things will work just fine.

1. npm uninstall -g truffle
2. truffle version(to check if its uninstalled)
3. npm install -g truffle@beta

You are good to go. This should fix the problem.

Comment: alas no, it didn't

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and this is how I made it work:
In truffle console, find out the gas limit for the last block. Use that number in your truffle.js. In my case gas: 4700036 worked.

```
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getBlock('latest').gasLimit
```

4700036

Answer (score 0):

To increase the gas limit in Truffle.
`which truffle` to get location of Truffle
Open in code editor.
`code /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/truffle`
currently the limit was set at 6721975so i just searched for this number
 `crtl+f 6721975`  Change it to 8000000 or whatever.
now in `truffle develop`  `web3.eth.getBlock('latest') // 8000000`